# JavaScript Caching DOM elements weird error

Tags: javascript, caching, dom

I am having trouble figuring out why my code will only work after I have made a call to get a document element that isn't stored in a variable. I am trying to store some DOM references into variables but my code won't interact with the DOM unless I preform an operation on the DOM element that I am trying to store. However, after I preform an operation on a single DOM element my other variables will allow an interface with the DOM as I had originally intended. I am linking two JSFiddles, the first is the one with the error and the second with the band-aid fix. Also below is the JavaScript code highlighting where the change is made.
Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/spencerduball/sLac9t3y/

https://jsfiddle.net/spencerduball/yyrjazLw/

```
(function() {
/* ----- VARIABLES ----- */
var score0, score1, current0, current1;

scoreO = document.getElementById('score-0');
score1 = document.getElementById('score-1');

current0 = document.getElementById('current-0');
current1 = document.getElementById('current-1');


/* ----- FUNCTIONS ----- */
function reset() {
    // BANDAID FIX HERE
    document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
    // END

    score1.textContent = '0';
    current0.textContent = '0';
    current1.textContent = '0';

};
reset();

}());
```

Comment: It looks like you have `scoreO` and `score0`, which are not the same

Comment: ... that would do it. I have been looking at this for an hour and a half and have been reread probably 10 different blogs and I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, the little things always seem to be the most evasive... :)

Answer (score -1):

Your variable is declared as `score0`.

```
var score0, score1, current0, current1;
```

But you're assigning to `scoreO`. (Capital "O" instead of number zero.)

```
scoreO = document.getElementById('score-0');
```

---

Some solutions are:

- Don't pre-declare the vars, since you're doing immediate assignment anyway

  ```
  var score0 = document.getElementById('score-0');
  // same for the others
  ```
- Use "strict mode" to get a useful error message on assignments to undeclared variables

  ```
  (function() { 
    "use strict";
    /* ----- VARIABLES ----- */
  ```
- Use a linter like [ESLint](http://eslint.org) or [JSHint](http://jshint.com). These will notify you of many different types of common programming errors, and will save you *lots* of time in the long run.